# option no se muestra en el select framework materialize

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]ya me muestra los datos con console.log() y pasa los option al select pero el select no se despliega y no muestra nada.

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').formSelect();
  });

function cargarEspecialidades(){
    var especialidadCambio2 = document.getElementById("especialidad1");
    var listar = 'listar';
    $.ajax(
        {
          data:{especialidad_id : especialidadCambio2.value, accion : listar},
            url:   "ins_doctor.php",
            type:  "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success:  function (data) 
            {
              $.each(data, function(i, v) {
               /* var o = new Option(v.nombre,v.idEspecialidad);
$(o).html(v.nombre);
$("#especialidad2").append(o);*/
                //$("#especialidad2").append(new Option(v.nombre,v.idEspecialidad));
                //console.log('<option value="' + v.idEspecialidad + '">' + v.nombre + '</option>');
               //$("#especialidad2").append('<option value="' + v.idEspecialidad + '">' + v.nombre + '</option>');
               //$("#especialidad2").material_select();
               $("#especialidad2").append(new Option(v.nombre,v.idEspecialidad))
            }
        });
}
</script>

<div class="input-field col s4 m4">
                                <i class="material-icons prefix">especialidad 2</i>
                                <select name="especialidad2" id="especialidad2">
                                </select>  
                                <label for="especialidad2"><?php echo 'Especialidad 2' ?></label>
                            </div>
```

aqui dejo el console.log()

```
   console.log('<option value="' + v.idEspecialidad + '">' + v.nombre + '</option>');

    <option value="1">Alergologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="3">Cardiologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="4">Gastroenterologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="5">Endocrinologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="6">Geriatria</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="7">Hematologia y hemoterapia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="8">Infectologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="9">Medicina aeroespacial</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="10">Medicina del deporte</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="11">Medicina del trabajo</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="12">Medicina de urgencias</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="13">Medicina familiar y comunitaria</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="14">Medicina fisica y rehabilitacion</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="15">Medicina intensiva</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="16">Medicina interna</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="17">Medicina legal y forense</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="18">Medicina preventiva y salud publica</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="19">Medicina veterinaria</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="20">Nefrologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="21">Neumologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="22">Neurologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="23">Nutriologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="24">Oftalmologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="25">Oncologia medica</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="26">Oncologia radioterapica</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="27">Pediatria</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="28">Psiquiatria</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="29">Rehabilitacion</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="30">Reumatologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="31">Toxicologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="32">Urologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="33">Cirugia cardiovascular</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="34">Cirugia general y del aparato digestivo</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="35">Cirugia oral y maxilofacial</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="36">Cirugia ortopedica y traumatologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="37">Cirugia pediatrica</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="38">Cirugia plastica, estetica y reparadora</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="39">Cirugia toracica</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="40">Neurocirugia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="41">Angiologia y cirugia vascular</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="42">Dermatologia medico-quirurgica y venereologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="43">Oftalmologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="44">Otorrinolaringologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="45">Urologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="46">Traumatologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="47">Ginecologia y obstetrica o tocologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="48">Analisis clinicos</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="49">Anatomia patologica</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="50">Bioquimica clinica</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="51">Farmacologia clinica</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="52">Genetica medica</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="53">Inmunologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="54">Medicina nuclear</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="55">Microbiologia y parasitologia</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="56">Neurofisiologia clinica</option>
nuevo_doctor.php:510 <option value="57">Radiodiagnostico o radiologia</option>
```

Comment: Qué es lo que te trae en data, puedes agregarlo como código en vez de imagen, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ya quedo

<script>

function cargarEspecialidades(){
  var especialidadCambio2 = document.getElementById("especialidad1");
  var listar = 'listar';
  $.ajax({
    data:{especialidad_id : especialidadCambio2.value, accion : listar},
    url:   "ins_doctor.php",
    type:  "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success:  function (data){
      //$('#especialidad2').remove();
      $.each(data, function(i, v) {
      $("#especialidad2").material_select();
      var o = new Option(v.nombre,v.idEspecialidad);
      $("#especialidad2").append(new Option(v.nombre,v.idEspecialidad));
      });
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que pude hacerlo funcionar de la siguiente forma:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="input-field col s4 m4">
    <select name="especialidad2" id="especialidad2"></select>  
    <label for="especialidad2">select</label>
</div>
</body> 


<script >
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').formSelect();
    cargarEspecialidades();
  });

function cargarEspecialidades(){
    $("#especialidad2").append(new Option("v.nombre","v.idEspecialidad"));
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: sigue igual no me muestra el select

Comment: Ya inicializaste tu select? Creo que no lo has hecho

    $("#especialidad2").formSelect();

Comment: te dejo todo el codigo que llevo ya quite lo que no es para el select

Comment: es todo el codigo js que llevo con  bootsrap usaba (id).refresh(); y listo pero con matelialize no se mucho

Comment: algo importante es que JQuery esté siendo importado antes de Materialize. Estás seguro que lo estás haciendo así en tu código? Puedes probar con el código de la edición.

Answer (score -1):

Al agregar nueva opción recargar lista:

```
$("#especialidad2").append(<option value="+v.idEspecialidad+">"+v.nombre+"</option>");
$('#especialidad2').formSelect();
```